# How to convert query to Json object in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The immediate answer to the question is to use `json_object`function.
However this function is not avliable on my DB as it's older version.
We have plans to upgrade but it will take a while.

How do I convert this:

```
SELECT name, phone, order_id FROM orders;

| name | phone | order_id
| Jack | 12345 |  120
| Jack | 12345 |  121
```

To this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Jack",
    "order_id": "120",
    "phone": 12345
  },
  {
    "name": "Jack",
    "order_id": "121",
    "phone": 12345
  }
]
```

In a SQL query without using `json_object` function

Comment: _How do I convert this:_ In what language?

Comment: @B001ᛦ SQL see the tag

Comment: This is a workaround, check this thread: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192208/mysql-return-json-from-a-standard-sql-query

Comment: _SQL see the tag_ I already have seen the tag but you don't want to do it in mysql

Comment: @B001ᛦ No, I want to run it as a SQL query in my Mysql db. What I said is that I don't have the json_object function that comes with new versions of MySQL